# How to speed up numpy.all and numpy.nonzero()?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to check if a point lies inside a bounding cuboid. The number of cuboids is very large (~4M). The code I come up with is:

```
import numpy as np

# set the numbers of points and cuboids
n_points = 64
n_cuboid = 4000000

# generate the test data
points = np.random.rand(1, 3, n_points)*512
cuboid_min = np.random.rand(n_cuboid, 3, 1)*512
cuboid_max = cuboid_min + np.random.rand(n_cuboid, 3, 1)*8

# main body: check if the points are inside the cuboids
inside_cuboid = np.all((points > cuboid_min) & (points < cuboid_max), axis=1)
indices = np.nonzero(inside_cuboid)
```

It takes 8 seconds to run  `np.all` and 3 seconds to run `np.nonzero` on my computer. Any idea to speed up the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reduce memory congestion for `all-reduction` with `slicing` along the smallest axis length of `3` to get `inside_cuboid` -

```
out = (points[0,0,:] > cuboid_min[:,0]) & (points[0,0,:] < cuboid_max[:,0]) & \
      (points[0,1,:] > cuboid_min[:,1]) & (points[0,1,:] < cuboid_max[:,1]) & \
      (points[0,2,:] > cuboid_min[:,2]) & (points[0,2,:] < cuboid_max[:,2])
```

Timings -

```
In [43]: %timeit np.all((points > cuboid_min) & (points < cuboid_max), axis=1)
2.49 s ± 20 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [51]: %%timeit
    ...: out = (points[0,0,:] > cuboid_min[:,0]) & (points[0,0,:] < cuboid_max[:,0]) & \
    ...:       (points[0,1,:] > cuboid_min[:,1]) & (points[0,1,:] < cuboid_max[:,1]) & \
    ...:       (points[0,2,:] > cuboid_min[:,2]) & (points[0,2,:] < cuboid_max[:,2])
1.95 s ± 10.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks. It helps a lot! It saves 60% of the time on my computer. But I need to make it at least 10 times faster. Any other ideas?

Comment: @f.c. Given your specific requirement of 10x speedup, a bounty might be fair from you, so that we all get the added motivation and also more attention.

Comment: I have turned to another solution to make it faster. Please check out my new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043572/how-to-speed-up-an-n-dimensional-interval-tree-in-python. Will add a bounty to that question if needed.